# Python thinks my file is empty even though it's not

Tags: python, file

so I'm using this code to check whether my file is empty:

```
def getPrizePool():
    global prizePool
    global win
    f = open("PrizePool.txt", "a+")
    data = f.read()
    if os.stat("PrizePool.txt").st_size==0:
        prizePool = 0
        setPrizePool()
    else:
        newPrizePool = int(f.readline(1))
        prizePool = newPrizePool

        newWin = int(f.readline(2))
        win = newWin
    f.close()
```

If the file is empty, create a new file and enter the variables prizePool and Win  into it. if it's not empty, I try to extract the values, which are on different lines, from the file and assign them to the variables. However, my code always goes down the "else" lane, even thouth my file clearly is not empty.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you point out where `fileEmpty` is assigned?  Also your indentation is incorrect.

Comment: is fileEmpty a function?  If so you should call it by adding parens.  i.e. fileEmpty() or possibly fileEmpty(f)

Comment: You open your file for appending. You should check your file sys via something like `os.path.getsize("/foo/bar/file")`.

Comment: Sorry guys. FileEmpty as a function was just a test, I changed it back now. How is my indentation incorrect (if it is, then that'll have to do with the copy+pasting into stackoverflow)?

Comment: Why would you read from a file first and then check if it is empty?

Comment: Immediately following `data = f.read()` - is the output of `print data` None?

Comment: Your 'else lane' is the case for a non-empty file. So it's what you want, no? But not sure if your reading of the file is correct. First you're reading `data` then a line as `newPrizePool`. You might also want to consider where your file cursor is.

Comment: Do you have the right file name. `a` and `a+` create the file if it does not exist, therefore it would be empty. What do you get if yo just test with `r`. Goes along with the comment by @alex

Comment: thanks @mikuszefski, that was my mistake. Removed "data = f.read()" and now it's correctly reading the file.

Comment: When you have the file open, pass its decriptor to os.stat, i.e. `os.stat(f.fileno())`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the full path to `PrizePool.txt` - e.g. `"C:\\Users\\ThisUser\\PrizePool.txt"`.

Per [the Python documentation on os.stat](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.stat), `os.stat()` accepts a full path, not a file name.

Comment: That's weird, because it works now (at least the checking for emptiness) after I removed data = f.read() . This was from an older version and it went through the whole file, leaving the rest of the file (empty) for the checking.

Answer (score 0):

You have the same exact problem like I had. Still don't know why `filename.read()` make Python consider my file empty.

My solution is to close and open the file again